# Jboss 7 security domain database: password encoding?

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x

This is my JBoss 7 application security domain configuration:

```
<security-domain name="effebi">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="Database" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/ProvaMySQL"/>
                            <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select password from utenti where username=?"/>
                            <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select r.codice, 'Roles' from ruoli r, utenti u where r.id=u.ruolo_id a$
                            <module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="MD5"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
```

In my "utenti" (principals) table I have a username "admin" with "21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3" as password (which is "admin" MD5 hashed).

I keep getting

> 13:08:14,181 ERROR
>   [org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager]
>   (http--127.0.0.1-8080-2) Login failure:
>   javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: Password
>   Incorrect/Password Required

How does my password / configuration have to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I simply needed to hash the password the JBoss-PicketBox way:

```
Util.createPasswordHash("MD5","BASE64",null, null, plainPassword);
```